# Arduino String.indexOf() not working

Tags: string, bluetooth, arduino, char, indexof

Been at this for hours and hours. The indexOf() function never returns > -1 even when I am seeing the characters print in the serial monitor, and the length of the string is increasing as characters come in.

```
String command;    

void loop() {

        while ( bleuart.available() ) {
            char ch;
            ch = bleuart.read();
            command += ch;
            Serial.print(ch);
        }

        Serial.println(command.length());

        if(command.indexOf("\n") > -1 ) {
           Serial.println("command:");
           Serial.println(command);
         }

    }
```

Comment: do you see new lines in the serial monitor? or just a long string? \n is the new line char

Comment: just a long string - no new lines. \n appears to be doing nothing.

Comment: If you see \n in the string then this is actually "\\"+" n" chars. Just for checking change indexof to find "\\n" and see if this match

Comment: @darc this worked! Don't quite understand why though. how does "\n" become "\\n"?

Comment: basically, \ is a special char that is used for escape sequences for example '\n' stands for new line. so if you want to print \ as string you need to add \ to escape it "\\", another example: let's say you want to use " inside a string you need to escape it with \ like this " \" ". you can see the full list of escape sequences here" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

Answer (score 0):

@darc is right, but there really shouldn't be a actual \n in the string if it comes from a ble module, which i assume. This should be a new line character (DEC 10) which \n should be the same as.

I see 3 deferent problems in your code.

1. Your `command` variable is never cleared, so it will just grow until
   you run out of memory. When you are done with the command, call
   `command = "";`
2. When you constructing your command string use `command.concat(ch);`instead of `command += ch;`
3. You should change `if(command.indexOf("\n") > -1 )` to `if(command.indexOf("\n") != -1 )`

See if that helps.